# gdal.Warp ignores some pixels when reprojecting it

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I have a tif in EPSG3035, pixel size 100x100m (very important for the study).
I use gdal.Warp to reproject the tif to EPSG4326 for getting lat/long of pixels along with their values. i am forcing the function to preserve the array area since some calculations follow.
The tif statistics are the following:
in_raster sum = 149580
out_raster sum = 136220

When visualizing the rasters (reds are out_raster) I notice there are some pixels not taken in the out_raster[image]

The code I am using is the following:

```
def cs2wgs84(input_raster, output_raster):
raster = gdal.Open(input_raster)
band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(0)
band.FlushCache()

rwidth = raster.RasterXSize
rheight = raster.RasterYSize

woptions = gdal.WarpOptions(width = rwidth ,height = rheight, 
    dstSRS='EPSG:4326',overviewLevel = 'NONE', dstNodata="0", resampleAlg = "near")
gdal.Warp(output_raster, input_raster, options=woptions)
band = None
raster= None
```

The results of the raster statistics are the following:
in_raster:

```
in_raster statistics:
Results:
{'MAX': 2267.493408203125,
'MEAN': 10.610063969353307,
'MIN': 0.0,
'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE': 'C:/Users/diana/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_tliQAH/a43f435d8d294ad3be80a681046b20bc/OUTPUT_HTML_FILE.html',
'RANGE': 2267.493408203125,
'STD_DEV': 81.50870519877743,
'SUM': 149580.68183994293,
'SUM_OF_SQUARES': 93655802.2197855}
```

out_raster statistics:

```
Results:
{'MAX': 2267.493408203125,
'MEAN': 9.321215707322825,
'MIN': 0.0,
'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE': 'C:/Users/diana/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_tliQAH/b68b22ce98064a5b9d20e616ef06b6fa/OUTPUT_HTML_FILE.html',
'RANGE': 2267.493408203125,
'STD_DEV': 76.70612274249875,
'SUM': 132062.9841413498,
'SUM_OF_SQUARES': 83356209.21407527}
```

Comment: Please clarify how do you know that some pixels have been ignored.

Comment: I have added the statistics in the question that denote the missed pixels

Comment: I feel that you suppose that you will have exactly same pixels in the re-projected EPSG:4326 image than you had in the original EPSG:3035 in pixel row/column units. I am not sure if that is a sound assumption. Coordinate systems are quite different and the nearest neighbor resampling may pick another pixel than you thought. If it is essential to have 100x100 pixel size in EPSG:3035, stay with it and don't warp.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is imperative to preserve shape and pixel size. For visualizing geospatial data without the need of any GIS software - basically, I would display point data in an excel map (the tool targets non experts) - I needed to convert those coordinates into lat/long simple points. Do you have any recommendations for this?